# Can I use AjaxForm for file uploading?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I saw some answers for how to upload file with the traditional form, I am wondering if it is possible to do it with mvc's ajax form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that no it's not. AJAX doesn't allow you to post a file in the form*.

The longer answer is that you can use an ordinary form (`@Html.BeginForm(...`)and then set its target to be a hidden iframe and post the file to there in the usual fashion and thus avoid refreshing your whole page. So you can simulate using AJAX to post a file. I can post some code if you'd like.

Or you can use an uploading plugin, but these usually use something like Flash or a hidden iframe behind the scenes.

*Footnote: I believe it will support uploading files soon. See here: http://www.profilepicture.co.uk/tutorials/ajax-file-upload-xmlhttprequest-level-2/*

Comment: Cool, thanks, so I will not spent more time on it. Thanks, have a good weekend.

Comment: No problem. Have a great weekend yourself.

Comment: So PHP does support the call, and mvc 3 doesn't... It sucks.

Comment: I think you could do that using MVC, but not all browsers support it. The specification is not yet finalised: http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/xhr/raw-file/tip/Overview.html